# What resources are available to convince a developer that Java stack traces are worth logging

Tags: java, stack-trace

I've just landed in a new code base. While working to make the application run locally, I noticed I was just getting one-liners for errors in the log and console output - no stack traces. I started searching code and the only thing I could find logged was the exception message. Ditto for "chaining" exceptions: only the message was being retained. I mentioned this to the project's sole developer and asked if it was an intentional design decision. The reply was, in part, "I don't think we'd gain much from [logging stack traces]."

From years of Java development, I know how valuable stack traces are: they tell you which line the exception happened on and you can track how you got there. You read the stack trace and the relevant code and that's probably enough to solve 80% (N.B.: statistic has no statistical backing) of errors you encounter.

I'm not looking for arguments about what to log or when - that's not the question, and it's been covered elsewhere. Really, this just seems like such a fundamental thing to me that I never thought of how to explain it other than that "strack traces show you where the error was." I was hoping I could quickly find a quote from *Effective Java* or the like, but Google hasn't turned up anything so far.

Any suggestions of authoritative, convincing sources for descriptions of why you should pay attention to stack traces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an intentional error in the code base and make him track it down :-).  Seriously, you have good arguments, if you could just demonstrate how much it helps and how much time it saves when tracking down a bug.

Comment: Upvoted. Really, the only way you can make them see the light is by leaving them in the dark for a while. If that's a logical analogy, of course.

Comment: Sometimes first-hand experience is the best resource. Fortunately, in most cases an intentional error isn't necessary. Most code bases have enough of them already without being sabotaged.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Google's coding standard](http://code.google.com/p/ontopia/wiki/CodingGuidelines)s for Java will be considered authoritative enough:

> Exceptions All methods must declare
>   the non-runtime-exceptions that they
>   may throw in their throws clause. If
>   they may throw several, all must be
>   listed, though shortening the list by
>   listing base classes instead of all
>   their children is encouraged, provided
>   information is not lost. In
>   particular, 'throws Exception' should
>   never appear on any method, except in
>   extreme cases, such as methods that
>   are so generic that they may in fact
>   throw any exception.
>
> Similarly, 'catch (Exception e)'
>   should not be used anywhere, since it
>   may catch exceptions that should not
>   be caught and thus hide problems. The
>   exact exceptions that are being caught
>   should be spelled out instead.
>
> For similar reasons, empty catch
>   blocks should be shunned (except in
>   testing code where exceptions are
>   expected), since they may also hide
>   problems and make debugging difficult.
>   If you know that the exception can
>   never happen always raise an
>   OntopiaRuntimeException with a message
>   like '"(IMPOSSIBLE) " + e', **and pass
>   in the caught exception to preserve
>   the stack trace.**

Comment: I don't think that's actually a Google project (ontopia.net has the same logo and no Google branding that I can find). But I definitely agree with the sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Apache Commons Logging, which happens to be used on this project, has these [guidelines for logging exceptions](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.1.1/guide.html#Logging%20Exceptions) that specify "logged with full stack trace."

I would still like to find something that states quite bluntly that this should be the default behavior unless you have a really, really good reason to do otherwise. Going into detail on *why* it is a good idea would be even better.